# Prove the identity: $\frac {1} {1+x^2} = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}, x\in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: calculus, number-theory

I want to prove that $$\frac {1} {1+x^2} = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2} = 1-x^2 +x^4 -x^6 +...+(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}+(-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2},  x\in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N$$.

That is, the identity in question holds for $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in \mathbb R$.

How can I prove this ? I cannot use induction since every time I change $n$ the sum changes ? I'm quite confused on how to proceed.

Comment: What convergens do you want to prove? You just have a geomeric sum. $a+aq+\ldots+aq^{n-1} = a\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-x^2+(x^2)^2+\ldots+(-x^2)^{n-1}=\frac{1-(-x^2)^n}{1-(-x^2)}=\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{1+x^2}$

Comment: what rule are you using here ?

Comment: The rule is written above in my comment.

Comment: But $\frac 1 {1+x^2} \neq \frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{1+x^2}$ ??

Comment: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}}{1+x^2}+(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}$ exactly  what you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you, by the way, how is the last equality in the identity I want to prove proved ? Is it trivial that the sum equal the sum of the right side ?

Comment: It is the same identity written in an expanded form

Comment: I see that now - I interpreted it as $(-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}$ was part of the summation. There should be parentheses to avoid this ambiguity. In summation, is it always only the first term that is part of the summation ($\sum$) ?